# Copying string literals in C into an character array

Tags: c, string

I have a string literal:

```
char *tmp = "xxxx";
```

I want to copy the string literal into an array.

For example:

- how do I copy `tmp` into an `char array[50]`?
- and how to copy one string literal to another?

Answer (score 10):

Use `strcpy()`, `strncpy()`, `strlcpy()` or `memcpy()`, according to your specific needs.

With the following variables:

```
const char *tmp = "xxxx";
char buffer[50];
```

You typically need to ensure your string will be null terminated after copying:

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
strncpy(buffer, tmp, sizeof buffer - 1);
```

An alternative approach:

```
strncpy(buffer, tmp, sizeof buffer);
buffer[sizeof buffer - 1] = '\0';
```

Some systems also provide `strlcpy()` which handles the NUL byte correctly:

```
strlcpy(buffer, tmp, sizeof buffer);
```

You could naively implement `strlcpy()` yourself as follows:

```
size_t strlcpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
{
    size_t len = strlen(src);

    if (len < n)
        memcpy(dest, src, len + 1);
    else {
        memcpy(dest, src, n - 1);
        dest[n - 1] = '\0';
    }

    return len;
}
```

The above code also serves as an example for `memcpy()`.

Finally, when you already know that the string will fit:

```
strcpy(buffer, tmp);
```

Comment: *This is safe regarding both the size of the string and the size of the array.* Well in your usage if the length of the string is greater than the size of you destination buffer, the destination buffer won't be null terminated.

Comment: @ouah: Good catch, feel free to edit or comment if you have more suggestions.

Comment: Great tip. `size_t len = strlen(src);` is probably better than `int len = strlen(src);`

Comment: What about a `buffer` of size 0?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy), it is pretty much well documented and easy to find:

```
const char* tmp = "xxxx";
// ...
char array[50];
// ...
strcpy(array, tmp);
```

But of course, you must make sure that the length of the string that you are copying is smaller than the size of the array. An alternative then is to use [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy), which gives you an upper limit of the bytes being copied. Here's another example:

```
const char* tmp = "xxxx";
char array[50];
// ...
array[49] = '\0';
strncpy(array, tmp, 49); // copy a maximum of 49 characters
```

If the string is greater than 49, the array will still have a well-formed string, because it is null-terminated. Of course, it will only have the first 49 characters of the array.

Comment: what if we do not know the size of the string literal being copied into the array?

Comment: @Anvita Potluri In `strcpy`, the number of bytes being copied are `strlen(src)`. By passing a null-terminated string, the size of the string literal is obtained by finding the first occurrence of the null terminator. Of course, both `strcpy` and `strncpy` hides these details, but you should know that C-strings are a sequence of characters with a '\0' character in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it this way:

char dst[40];

snprintf(dst, sizeof(dst), "%s", "string literal");

Comment: i believe snprintf(dst, sizeof(dst), "%s",tmp); would work

Answer (score 0):

```
// For Microsoft Visual C++:

  char dst[40];

  strcpy_s(dst, sizeof(dst), "A String Literal");

// if you are not using Microsoft Visual C++:

#ifndef _MSC_VER
int strcpy_s(char* dst, int dst_len, const char* src) {
  int i;
  if (dst == 0)
    return 0;

  if (dst_len == 0)
    return 0;

  if (src == 0) {
    dst[0] = 0;
    return 0;
  }

  for (i=0; i < src_len-1; i++) {
   if (src[i] == 0) {
      break;
   }
   src[i] = dst[i];
  }
  src[i] = 0;
  return i;
}
#endif
```